# android.support.v7 jar file is nonexistent

Tags: android, jar

I have looked in ../extras/android/support/v7 and there are 6 folders, but no jar file.

I am unable to start a simple application at the moment because my only activity is riddled with errors because of this missing jar file.

I have tried reinstalling the support library, but no dice.

Is there any way I can download this file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Support v7 has resources so no jar file available. You can retrieve from maven repository, but it is not in maven central so you need to set up android maven repository using sdk manager.